# extract zipped folder contents into the root

Tags: php, extract, php-ziparchive

i am trying to extract the contents of a zipped folder into the root of the website i have a directory called zip.zip but everything i try creates a directory called zip, is there a way to extract the contents into the root

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
    if ($zip->open("zip.zip")){
        $path = getcwd() . "/";
        $path = str_replace("\\","/",$path);
        echo $path;
        echo $zip->extractTo($path);
        $zip->close();
        echo 'Done.';
    } else {
        echo "Error";
    }
?>
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this

```
<?php

$path = 'zip.zip';

$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open($path) === true) {
    for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
        $filename = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
        $fileinfo = pathinfo($filename);
        copy("zip://".$path."#".$filename, "".$fileinfo['basename']);
    }                  
    $zip->close();                  
}

?>
```

thanks any way

Comment: great that you are sorted :) but I'll just leave this little note suggesting that it's preferable to cite any sources [*» php.net*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.extractto.php#100802)